# Okta login page goes to infinite loop after user authentication

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

[image]

like this

My Angular app integrated Okta access and user management API. The application backend is hosted in AWS Beanstaik and front end angular app is hosted S3.

I checked the network response by chrome dev tools and I got this

`{"expiresAt":"2021-09-03T02:59:39.000Z","status":"SUCCESS","sessionToken":"20111F_ApSDB7zPMeay5y2V4nG8yUlU0i4ICgHyAOMYvc5Miq743wse","_embedded":{"user":{"id":"00ubopju1CRuT02ji5d6","passwordChanged":"2021-03-13T22:58:33.000Z","profile":{"login":"Rafi12534@Gmail.com","firstName":"Mohammed","lastName":"Samsuddin","locale":"en","timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles"}}},"_links":{"cancel":{"href":"https://dev-97379822.okta.com/api/v1/authn/cancel","hints":{"allow":["POST"]}}}}`

login component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import * as OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget';



import myAppConfig  from '../../config/my-app-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  oktaSignin: any;

  constructor(private oktaAuthService: OktaAuthService) {

    this.oktaSignin = new OktaSignIn({
      logo: 'assets/images/logo_for_favicon.png',
      features: {
        registration: true
      },
      baseUrl: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0], // return everything in url before '/oauth2'
      clientId: myAppConfig.oidc.clientId,
      redirectUri: myAppConfig.oidc.redirectUri,
      authParams: {
        pkce: true,         // Proof Key for Code Exchange.
                            // Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE, pronounced pixie) 
                            // extension describes a technique for public clients to mitigate
                            // the threat of having the authorization code intercepted.
        issuer: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer,
        scopes: myAppConfig.oidc.scopes
      }
    });


   }



  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.oktaSignin.remove();   // remove previous element that rendered there

    this.oktaSignin.renderEl({
      el: '#okta-sign-in-widget'}, // render element with given id
                                  // this name should be same as div tag id in login.component.html
      (response) => {
        if (response.status === "SUCCESS") {
          this.oktaAuthService.signInWithRedirect();
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        throw error;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

After authentication okta try to authenticate again that's what maybe put it into infinite loop.

Comment: would help if you showed your widget hosting page, but I guess, you need to do something after you got SUCCESS after authentication. Usually it's a redirect to other page or something else (hiding widget or similar)

Comment: You can actually check out the website: (www.luv2shop.net) the signup works but login authenticate properly and sent an success response but not going to the redirect page after sign in. check out chrome dev tools.

Comment: It works on my local host but not is AWS S3. If you need any additional information feel free to ask. I am stuck with this problem for long time and I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out the problem?

Comment: I believe the issue is here `this.oktaSignin.renderEl` For OIDC apps you want to use something like `showSignInToGetTokens` or `showSignInAndRedirect` Taken from https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#oktasignin

Comment: surprisingly it works in safari browser but not in google chrome. although it works on google chrome in my phone.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the same problem (works locally, even after building the app, but not once pushed to an hosted env). It successfully calls "/api/v1/authn", but then it freezes out of nowhere (no error or anything).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solve it like this:

In the my-app-config file in your case, Its probably configured like that, pointing localhost in the redirectUri:
[image: Its probably configured like that, pointing localhost in the redirectUri]

Just change it to your real url for example:

```
   redirectUri: 'http://example.com/login/callback'
```

And it should resolve the auth loop.

I hope that solves the problem for you!

Comment: Thank you! I had 8080 used, and flipped it to another port. Didn't think they would actually hardcode the port. After switching it and modifying my app redirects in Okta Settings accordingly, it went through.